# How to specify max key length in KEYS operation REDIS

Tags: redis

Does anyone know how to specify the maximum key length for redis `KEYS` operation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KEYS` is a dangerous command - do not use it for anything but development purposes. That said, the command's pattern matching capabilities are basic and do not include the ability to specify a maximum length for key names.

Answer (score 1):

@**Itamar Haber** just gave you the best advice.

However... just for the sake of completion, you can do that using the `?` pattern.

So, if you want to match any key that has 4 chars exactly, you can do:

```
KEYS ????
```